# Linux - block all connections except VPN dynamic IP domain

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, dns

I have a VPN that I connect to (OpenVPN) via domain name, not via IP. VPN's IP is dynamic, can change any moment. I want my machine's only communication with the internet to be `my.vpn.domain.com` and **nothing** else.

I would use a OpenDNS lookup as the `my.vpn.domain.com` lookup, and I believe that's secure enough (assuming it also blocks all IPs/connections that don't belong to the vpn domain), and I see no better/other IP-layer based options.

My purpose is to have a VPN killswitch that is actually good (without leaks or manual intervention).

Once I have connected to the VPN via its domain, I should be able have the `my.vpn.domain.com` restriction lifted, and let my firewall / iptables allow only connections through tun0. Then if VPN connection drops, start again through `my.vpn.domain.com` only, then vpn connect, then allow all tun0 etc..

Can this be done via hosts file or how else? I'm new to linux scripting.

Comment: Is the VPN running on a router or the end PC? You should be able to stop leakage by allowing VPN traffic onto the Internet but not anything else. Rather then relying on IP address of the endpoint, you can use iptables to block everything except traffic on port 1194 (for VPN) and anything traversing the tunnel device ( eg iptables -I OUTPUT tun+ allow) the tun+ means any tunnel interface.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this:

**Set up iptables to drop all dns queries on your non-tunnel interface, but allow for my.vpn.domain**

```
iptables -A INPUT -o eth0 -p udp -s $your_dns_server --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DENY

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -m string --string my.vpn.domain --algo bm -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -d $your_dns_server --dport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

**Configure openvpn to send all traffic down tunnel once established**

OpenVpn by default does not route all traffic down the tunnel, but can be configured to do so with `redirect-gateway`.  Read the section 'Routing all client traffic (including web-traffic) through the VPN' [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect) .

**Configure openvpn to reconnect automatically**

play around with ping-restart and keepalive configuration values.

```
ping 10
ping-restart 120
push "ping 10"
push "ping-restart 60"

or equivalently:

keepalive 10 60
```

Tweak as necessary but in a perfect world, if you dial in your iptables settings and the openvpn keepalive settings,  your machine should only be able to query for my.vpn.domain, establish and reestablish an openvpn connection, and route down that connection only when available.

If you haven't already read the openvpn doc about **Running an OpenVPN server on a dynamic IP address** to make sure your server side config is correct.

...and if the client machine is remote, make sure you allow SSH via iptables so you don't lock yourself out. Tread lightly if you're new to iptables.

Comment: This sounds really good Timmy. I was convinced you could only do layer 3+4 stuff with IPTables, that you couldn't work with domain names, only IPs. I'll get to it and accept the answer once I figured stuff out.

Comment: No, actually this doesn't work. IPtables **is** layer 3+4. When you make a rule for a domain name, that domain gets resolved to an IP address at the moment of its creation (no good for dynamic ip domains). Also, even if it did work, it would only stop connections that go through DNS resolution. Won't stop anyone from using IPs directly. Pretty sure we need layer 7.

Comment: what if you call a script on disconnect that flushes dns cache, flushes iptables and queries for my.vpn.domain again before reconnecting.   i.e. config :  client-disconnect disconnectscript.sh .     Im assuming here that the server ip isn't going to be constantly changing and the reconnect event is occurring only when it does.   I also didn't put in a rule that denies all outbound traffic on the interface, which would bar all traffic (except querying DNS for your server.   dirty, but doable

Comment: I down voted this because allowing DNS through Ethernet is a prime way if leaking IP details.

Comment: aw dang.  he did say in his question that he was going to use a DNS lookup, though.   Alternatively, perhaps getting really silly and setting his openvpn server as a client, that runs a script to query its external IP address on server start and client disconnect that then updates a secure private bind master server, and have that server on update update the hosts file entry on his client server, which he configures to be an openvpn server, but provides a default gateway of down the client tunnel.  its silly but, it works,   i did something like this a few years ago. i can try and dig it up.

Comment: It is really annoying that there isn't a more straightforward way. You'd think people and enterprises would want proper VPN killswitched connections in linux/windows etc. I suppose this is what PFSense does: has a server that is open to the internet but does nothing other than what you told it: connect to VPN, then forward only that connection to your network..